# Rinkeby Authenticated Faucet is offline

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I wonder if anyone has successfully requested ether on https://faucet.rinkeby.io/? I followed the instruction and it kept saying Faucet offline. Any workaround for this? or then will it be fixed? just need to some eth to test :(

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwjZC.png)

Comment: funny this exists so quickly, I'm also seeing that same timed out icon appearing over n over whilst trying to follow a moralis NFT contract guide on YT...

Answer (score 3):

**Update**
After Eth 2.0 and deprecation of rinkeby testnet this faucet no longer works.

Yes it is not working for a long time.
Right now there is only one working faucet for rinkeby ether that is by Chainlink. Try this you can get 0.1 eth (multiple times)
https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby

Comment: opensea only supports rinkeby testnet.

Comment: Ok! The link is for rinkeby anyways, yes I found out the hard way that kovan isnt on testnets for opensea

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem, it kept prompting "faucet offline".
You can use https://rinkebyfaucet.com/ instead to get 0.1 RinkebyETH.